# Converting POSIX ACL to NFSv4 ACL

Tags: linux, nfs, acl

We are facing data migrating from nfsv3 to nfsv4.

We set POSIX ACL for some folders and files on nfsv3 by using setfacl which are exporting from Linux box as a nfs server. Now we are going to migrate the data to NetApp with nfsv4 enabled, as the POSIX ACL isn't supported by NetApp, once the data copied to nfsv4, the ACL which set by setfacl command would be lost, and you have to set nfsv4 ACL by manual accordingly.

I don't know that if there is a tool that can be easily used for converting POSIX ACL to nfsv4 ACL, instead of writing a script to check POSIX ACL by using getfacl.